# How do I install deps for CPAN module without installing it?

Tags: perl, deployment, module, installation, cpan

This is a follow-up to my previous question [about developing Perl applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679835). Let’s say I develop an application as a CPAN module using `Module::Install`. Now I upload the code to the production server, say using a `git push`, and I would like to install the application dependencies listed in `Makefile.PL`. If I simply run `cpan .`, the thing tries to install the application like a regular Perl module, ie. starts to copy the modules and documentation to standard Perl directories all over the system.

Is this the way it’s supposed to be? Do you install the application into the standard Perl directories? I am used to having my Perl applications in one directory with separate `lib`. Otherwise it seems I’d have to manage a lot of other things, like installing the resources somewhere on path etc. If I just want to install the deps declared in `Makefile.PL` and run the application tests to make sure everything works, what should I do?

(Is this documented somewhere? I mean, is there something like best practice for deploying and updating non-trivial Perl applications? Or is everybody doing this his own way?)

Comment: Why aren't you using [`Dist::Zilla`][dzil] `Module::Install` is very old. [dzil]: http://dzil.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, but I think what you're looking for is

```
perl Makefile.PL
make installdeps
```

Comment: I tried this one and didn't succeed.That's because this works only for distributions based on `Module::Install` according to http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/1528/five-ways-to-install-modules-prereqs-by-hand/

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [Module::Install](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Install), you're really using [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) behind the scenes. You can use all of the MakeMaker features and the targets it provides. Although the documentation doesn't show every feature, there are some valuable things to be found in the generated `Makefile`.

However, `MakeMaker` is old news and most everyone has asked Santa Claus for it to disappear. If you want better control, including creating your own targets and process, [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build) is orders of magnitude easier to work with as well as cross-platform (even if that just means not using a different `make`, `gmake`, or whatever on the same OS on different boxes). If you deviate from the normal, consumer-grade installation process, you're life will be easier without `MakeMaker`.

Some people appreciate the brevity of the `Module::Install` build file, but once constructed, you don't spend a lot of time messing with your build file so it's not that much of a real benefit. When the little benefit you get locks you into `MakeMaker`, it's not a win at all.

---

A 2014 update: [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build) has now fallen out of favor and needs a maintainer. It never quite got to the point where people could use it to build and distribute XS modules. It was deprecated in Perl v5.19 although you can still get it from CPAN.

Comment: I have changed to Module::Build, feels better. The 0.36 release adds an `installdeps` action that does precisely what I was asking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at [Module::ScanDeps](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3A%3AScanDeps) to generate a list of dependent modules for installing.  Or [Par::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR%3A%3APacker) for packaging up the whole thing as an "app".

Comment: Thank you (+1), but that’s not quite what I want. M::S is quite orthogonal to the whole Module::Install machinery I would like to use. As for P::P, I am afraid it would make things unnecessarily complicated. Most of my applications are Catalyst web apps and it’s quite convenient for me to have a ‘live’ repository on the server when I want to fix something.