# What is the Module::Build equivalent to ExtUils::MakeMaker INST_SCRIPT?

Tags: perl, makemaker, module-build

I want to convert a project from use of [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) to [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild).
As the Makefile.PL is mostly default and [Module::Build::Convert](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aConvert) did not work for me (see below) I want to convert it manually but did not find the equivalent of INST_SCRIPT to place the executables in Perl's bin/ directory.

My WriteMakefile looks like this.

```
WriteMakefile(
    NAME                => 'Project',
    AUTHOR              => q{Mugen Kenichi <mugen.kenichi@uninets.eu>},
    VERSION_FROM        => 'lib/Project.pm',
    INST_SCRIPT         => 'script/',
    ($ExtUtils::MakeMaker::VERSION >= 6.3002
      ? ('LICENSE'=> 'perl')
      : ()),
    PL_FILES            => {},
    PREREQ_PM => {
        'JSON' => 0,
        'Log::Log4perl' => 0,
        'Proc::Daemon'  => 0,
        'Term::ANSIColor' => 0,
        'MooseX::Declare' => 0.34,
        'MooseX::Log::Log4perl' => 0,
        'Moose::Util::TypeConstraints' => 0,
        'MooseX::Templated::Role' => 0,
        'Template' => 0,
        # for testing
        'Test::More' => 0,
        'MooseX::Params::Validate' => 0,
        'File::Temp' => 0,
        'Sub::Exporter::ForMethods' => 0,
        'Data::Section' => 0,
    },
    dist                => { COMPRESS => 'gzip -9f', SUFFIX => 'gz', },
    clean               => { FILES => 'Project-*' },
);
```

I tried to use [Module::Build::Convert](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aConvert) but make2build throws errors i could not resolve:

```
Variable "$regex" will not stay shared at (re_eval 32) line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $lines[0] in pattern match (m//) at /home/mak/perl5/lib/perl5/Module/Build/Convert.pm line 1305, <DATA> line 1.
```

perl version:

```
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for x86_64-linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's what your *Makefile.PL* looks like, leave it like that. Don't switch to Module::Build, which appears to be an abandoneed build system. No one maintains Module::Build anymore, and until Leon Timmermans comes out with the next thing, unless there's some feature in Module::Build you absolutely must have, there's no reason to convert to it.

Having said that though, I create the list of script files and use it as the value for `script_files`. It's not as nice. See my [Build.PL for Unicode::Tussle](http://api.metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/Unicode-Tussle-1.03/Build.PL).

Comment: Thank you for the information and the example. Actually part of my motivation to switch was your answer (addmittedly nearly two years old) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708332/how-do-i-install-deps-for-cpan-module-without-installing-it/1710705#1710705.

Comment: Another was the installdeps target I miss with MakeMaker. Could you recommend another build helper module that provides it or something similar?

Comment: Well, that answer still stands, but note that I strongly qualified that use of Module::Build to say that you should use it if you want to deviate from standard practice.